# spring-data-jdbc integrate with mybatis

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data, mybatis, spring-data-jdbc

I am currently using myBatis for my project, it is good for complex SQL, but I found that I need to create many redundant SQL for basic CRUD. So I come across `spring-data-jdbc` ([here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jdbc/docs/current/reference/html/#jdbc.mybatis)), which is a very nice library (similar to `spring-data-jpa` but without JPA persistence) to help to generate CRUD SQL statement via method name.

The guide on their official website on how to integrate with myBatis is very vague, I couldn't find any other source which showing how to do that. Basically I am looking for a way to do like below:

```
@Repository
@Mapper
public interface PersonRepository extends CrudRepository<Person, Long> {

    //via spring-data-jdbc
    List<Person> findAll();
    
    //via spring-data-jdbc
    List<Person> findByFirstName(String name);
    
    //via myBatis, the actual query is in PersonMapper.xml
    List<Person> selectAllRow();
}
```

As you can see, when I call `findAll` and `findByFirstName`, they will be handled by `spring-data-jdbc`. When I call `selectAllRow`, it will look for corresponding myBatis mapper file for actual SQL. In this way I can combine two mechanism to handle simple CRUD query and complex query (via myBatis) together.

But above doesn't work, so currently I have to split them into two interface, one for `PersonRepository`, and another one for `PersonMapper`, which is not a very nice design.

Anyone has done similar before?

Comment: Take a look at https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-examples/tree/main/jdbc/mybatis

Comment: @JensSchauder I have checked this before, it looks like the integration is just delegate the SQL call (instead of using NamedParameterJdbcTemplate) to myBatis (using SqlSession), although we are calling method from CrudRepository, but it goes to myBatis mapper XML. The problem with this is, I can't link up the custom method to myBatis SQL query, it looks like it has limited set of method we can use https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jdbc/docs/current/reference/html/#jdbc.mybatis.conventions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Having two separate interfaces one for repository and another for mybatis mapper is just how mybatis integration in `spring-data-jdbc` works as of now (version 2.2.1).

Mapper is just an implemenation detail of the spring data repository and just should not be used by the clients, so it should not be an issue.

What you want can be probably done but will require quite some work and might not be worth it.

`@Repository` annotation instructs `spring-data-jdbc` to create a proxy implementing `PersonRepository` with all the machinery of fetching/saving objects to the database.

`@Mapper` on the other hand instructs mybatis-spring to create another proxy that will handle queries from the mapping provided in xml or via annotations on the interface method.

Only one of this proxies can be injected in the places where you are going to use `PersonRepository`. What you can do is to create your own proxy for `PersonRepository` that will create both `spring-data-jdbc` and mybatis proxy and will dispatch calls to them. But the complexity of this solution will be rather high compared to a simple class that delegates to two separate `PersonRepository` and `PersonMapper`.

Update: it seems there is a way to combine mybatis mapper with repository as described in this comment https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-jdbc/pull/152#issuecomment-660151636

This approach uses [repository fragments](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.custom-implementations) to add mybatis fragment to the repository implementation.

Comment: ok, it looks like similar request was raised before... looks like it has been pending... https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-jdbc/issues/598

Comment: yes, and even a PR exists https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-jdbc/pull/152

Comment: oh, that pull request mentioned a so-called "Customizing Individual Repositories"https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jdbc/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.single-repository-behavior, which is quite similar to what I am looking, although it still requires extra interface, but at least we can make repository call via a single interface instead of two.